# Changing titles after pivoting

Tags: python, pandas

Below you can see the format of my data. I am trying to pivot this data into a desirable format. Below you can see my data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id_n":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19"],
                               "kind_i":["1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","19","20","23","25","26"],
                               "gross_i":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]})
            
    table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['gross_i'], index=['id_n'],
                                columns=['kind_i'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

[image]

After pivoting above you can see the appearance of my table.

I am not satisfied with the titles of columns and I want to change in format e.g kind_1, kind_2, kind_3 ... and kind_26. Please see pic below.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change from dataframe pivot to series `pivot` , then `add_prefix`

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='gross_i', index='id_n',
                       columns='kind_i', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0).add_prefix('kind_')
table
Out[462]: 
kind_i  kind_1  kind_10  kind_11  kind_12  ...  kind_6  kind_7  kind_8  kind_9
id_n                                       ...                                
1            1        0        0        0  ...       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: beat me to it ;)

Comment: I tried these lines of code but Id_n is not in sam line with kind_i1. Is it possible to be in the same line?

Comment: @silent_hunter  table  = table.reset_index()